How to nicely display table comparing translations of words across many languages?
I am landing on a design such as this for single word overview cards.

Perhaps it can still be improved, showing the native Chinese term (or in any language, the native script), the romanization, the IPA pronunciation, and a brief 1-liner description. And then the role/part of speech, and the audio button if there is audio.
What is the best way to compactify such a table, especially in regards to making it so that we can compare 20+ languages on the same English word. Wiktionary does it with ugly tables.

Another approach would be to have a row with the English term, then a second row containing a box with a grid layout (everything equal width), and have the language written in small letters, and the native/roman words written below. So if there were 20 languages, maybe the grid would fit 3 into an 800 width container, per row, for ~7 rows. For each word.
Otherwise we can have a horizontally scrolling table, but I feel like on mobile you will never see the far right items in that table (languages 15-20 let's say).
How would you display this much information like that Wiktionary example?

Is this purely mobile? The second approach is difficult to imagine. Please add a basic wireframe of the concept if possible.

Generally speaking - this is what tables are for, and they work great. Usually no reason to reinvent the wheel. However, they are notoriously difficult to transfer to mobile, and usually something's got to give - meaning that you'll probably need to compromise on one of the dimensions. Either viewing many translation for a single word at a time, or one translation for multiple words at a time. One common solution is introducing internal navigation, something like this for instance.


Oh I like that, that makes a lot of sense! Thanks.
